# How do I write data to the SD card in Android via a StorageVolume?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am desperately trying to write data to the SD card with my app. I am attempting to use the StorageVolume class to do this, but I am having lots of trouble.

This is what I have:

```
StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager)context.getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
List<StorageVolume> storageVolumeList = storageManager.getStorageVolumes();
for(StorageVolume volume : storageVolumeList){
    if(volume.getDescription(context).equalsIgnoreCase("sd card")){
        Intent write_to_sd_card_intent = volume.createAccessIntent(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        if(write_to_sd_card_intent != null){

context.startActivityForResult(write_to_sd_card_intent, Constants.WRITE_TO_SD_CARD_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```

When I do this, it does ask my permission to write to that location, which is good, but I don't know what to do next. I looked at **[this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/scoped-directory-access)** article, but it doesn't say what to do after the `startActivityForResult()`.

I don't believe I can use the same procedures for a normal intent, as `volume.createAccessIntent()` creates an intent differently than a "normal" intent, because you are not passing the next activity into the method parameter.

Also, I don't see a way to use a `StorageVolume` to get a path to write my data to.

Any suggestions?

---

As an FYI, I have tried all of the Android approved methods of writing to the SD card with no luck. See my previous post **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710831/is-there-a-definitive-answer-for-how-to-write-data-to-the-external-sd-card-in)**

Comment: FYI, an `Intent` on Android is just _an abstract description of an operation to be performed_. It can sure be used to start another `Activity` but it's far from its sole purpose.

Comment: @shkschneider I don't know what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: I'm just noticing, regarding your comment about a "normal intent", that an Intent has many more usages behind starting an `Activity`. The italic part was from Google ^^

Comment: @shkschneider I meant "normal" as in the way the `Intent` is created.